# how to access a file from view folder to frontend in laravel 5.8?

Tags: laravel

i have a file called "index.blade" in a view inside a folder name "home". now i am trying to make that folder as my front end for 127.0.0.1:8000 . it is showing me error as tried to give routes.

i have tried to used controller named FrontendController to provide route

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
>   Undefined variable: students (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\Student01\resources\views\home\index.blade.php)

Comment: my code is:<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FrontendController extends Controller
{
 public function index(){
    return view('home.index');
}
}

Comment: Add your view and controller code as well in your question

Comment: Its looks issue from your blade file, can you please paste the code of it as well.

Comment: @KshitizDhungel what is the code in your `resources\views\home\index.blade.php` ?

Comment: sorry i am new to use stackoverflow so i am making lots of mess

Comment: Have you created any models?

Comment: please help me how do i post that code of index.blade.php

Comment: Edit the question and add there or paste here...https://pastebin.com/  > save and then link.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ZANycGrf

Comment: https://pastebin.com/qApcvnR1

Comment: https://pastebin.com/teSRQv2R

Comment: than you very much

Comment: You have `students` table in database correct?

Comment: yes i have correct database .

Comment: problem is solved thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1):

issue with students variable.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Students; 

class FrontendController extends Controller
{
 public function index()
    {
        $students = Students::get();
        return view('home.index', compact('students'));
    }
}
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/qApcvnR1 but it showed error   .................                         
 Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Students' not found

Comment: Do you have students table? you should create model for students table

Comment: i have created model it works for login but not while i am tring to access that system to frontend

Comment: I checked. you should call model in controller.
use App\Students;

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `DB::table()` Like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FrontendController extends Controller
{
 public function index()
    {
        $students = \DB::table('students')->get();
        return view('home.index', compact('students'));
    }
}
```